# No vuex store detected - Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm working on Quasar, and want to add store module. I did ran the `quasar new store <name>` command, but in the console of browser, I always get the message: "No vuex store detected". Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], without that it is not really possible to tell what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instructions:

right click on browser page -> Inspect -> Click on Devtool Vue

Answer (score 0):

One satuation is:

[image: Sample code]

Need put `Vue.config.devtools = true` before creating Vuex.Store(...).